# How to increase read and write speed ifstream and ofstream for std::vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++, fstream

I have to read and write a lot of data to and from disk, and the way I currently do it is via these two functions:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> read_vector_from_disk(std::string path)
{
    std::ifstream instream(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<uint8_t> data((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(instream)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    return data;
}

bool write_vector_to_disk(std::vector<uint8_t> data, std::string path)
{
    std::ofstream outstream(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    std::ostream_iterator<uint8_t> out_iterator(outstream);
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), out_iterator);
    return true;
}
```

And I am dissapointed with the read and write times I with this approach:

```
File name: "1_IMGP3437.JPG"
File size: 11987566 Bytes
Average read time: 34554.9 Microseconds
Average write time: 186344 Microseconds
```

Based on read/write benchmarking tools I have used, I was expecting close to 520 MB/s for reading and 495 MB/s for writing (on average).

What can I do to optimize the process? I have been looking at memory mapped I/O but I am not sure that is the way to go. Based on "reviews" I have read of memory mapped I/O.

The full source code for my benchmark can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/looopTools/5ea6b21dfa33e70890cb486b0db222e1

And the Makefile: https://gist.github.com/looopTools/ccfee5b669caf44c3fa2993c48a12332

Comment: First thing I'd try is not using C++ I/O which is notoriously slow. Try C I/O or something from your O/S API.

Comment: For reading, you could get the size of the file and resize the vector to that size. Then just do a single [read](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) directly into the [vector data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data). For writing just [write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) the vector data directly.

Comment: @Lars Your title "How to reduce ... speed ..." shocked me! :)

Comment: @L.F. doh Thanks

Comment: @VictorGubin That synchronization is only used for standard input, output and error, not arbitrary files.

Answer (score 0):

With memory mapped files you avoid a lot of copying between the kernel and user space on read and write, which is much faster.

Your code to read into a vector reallocates the vector while reading the file and that slows it down. The benchmark below creates the vector of the file size to avoid reallocations and that speeds up reading considerably.

The MiB/s numbers are large because the kernel caches the file data in the page cache so that no actual disk I/O happens during the benchmark.

Results:

```
Input file: /home/max/Downloads/1.tif
Output dir: /home/max/tmp
File name: "1.tif"
File size: 63106564

*** Benchmarking method IOstreams *** 
Checksums: 132769358678
Average read time: 27225.9us
Average read speed: 2210.51MiB/s
Average write time: 670221us
Average write speed: 2210.51MiB/s

*** Benchmarking method mmap *** 
Checksums: 132769358678
Average read time: 9554.5us
Average read speed: 6298.93MiB/s
Average write time: 28803.9us
Average write speed: 6298.93MiB/s
```

Code:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

struct IostreamTag {};
struct MmapTag {};

inline char const* name(IostreamTag) { return "IOstreams"; }
inline char const* name(MmapTag) { return "mmap"; }

template<class T>
inline T& get_ref(T& t) { return t; }

template<class T>
inline T& get_ref(std::unique_ptr<T>& t) { return *t; }

template<class C>
uint64_t get_checksum(C const& data) {
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    for(uint8_t c : data)
        sum += c;
    return sum;
}

std::vector<char> read(IostreamTag, std::string const& path) {
    size_t file_size = std::experimental::filesystem::file_size(path);
    std::vector<char> data(file_size); // Avoid memory reallocations.
    std::ifstream instream(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    instream.read(data.data(), file_size);
    if(file_size != static_cast<size_t>(instream.tellg()))
        throw;
    return data;
}

std::unique_ptr<boost::iostreams::mapped_file> read(MmapTag, std::string const& path) {
    return std::make_unique<boost::iostreams::mapped_file>(path, boost::iostreams::mapped_file::readwrite);
}

void write(IostreamTag, std::vector<char> const& data, std::string const& path) {
    std::ofstream outstream(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    std::ostream_iterator<uint8_t> out_iterator(outstream);
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), out_iterator);
}

void write(MmapTag, boost::iostreams::mapped_file const& data, std::string const& path) {
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_params params;
    params.path = path;
    params.flags = boost::iostreams::mapped_file::readwrite;
    params.new_file_size = data.size();
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file f(params);
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), f.begin());
}

size_t print_file_data(std::string path)     {
    std::experimental::filesystem::path p(path);

    std::cout << "File name: " << p.filename() << '\n';
    size_t file_size = std::experimental::filesystem::file_size(p);
    std::cout << "File size: " << file_size << '\n';
    return file_size;
}

template<class Tag>
void benchmark(Tag t, std::string const& input_file, std::string const& output_directory, size_t file_size) {
    std::cout << "\n*** Benchmarking method " << name(t) << " *** \n";

    uint64_t read_speed_total = 0;
    uint64_t checksums = 0;
    uint32_t iterations = 11;

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto data = read(t, input_file);
        checksums += get_checksum(get_ref(data));
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto c_start = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(start.time_since_epoch());
        auto c_end = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end.time_since_epoch());
        if(i)
            read_speed_total += static_cast<uint64_t>(c_end.count() - c_start.count());
    }

    double avg_read_time = read_speed_total / static_cast<double>((iterations - 1));
    std::cout << "Checksums: " << checksums << '\n';
    std::cout << "Average read time: " << avg_read_time << "us" << '\n';
    std::cout << "Average read speed: " << (file_size / (1024 * 1024.)) / (avg_read_time / 1000000) << "MiB/s" << '\n';

    std::experimental::filesystem::path in(input_file);
    std::experimental::filesystem::path out(output_directory);
    out = out / in.filename();
    auto data = read(t, input_file);

    uint64_t write_speed_total = 0;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::experimental::filesystem::remove(out);
        write(t, get_ref(data), out.string());
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto c_start = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(start.time_since_epoch());
        auto c_end = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end.time_since_epoch());
        if(i)
            write_speed_total += static_cast<uint64_t>(c_end.count() - c_start.count());
    }

    double avg_write_time = write_speed_total / static_cast<double>((iterations - 1));
    std::cout << "Average write time: " << avg_write_time << "us" << '\n';
    std::cout << "Average write speed: " << (file_size / (1024 * 1024.)) / (avg_read_time / 1000000) << "MiB/s" << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        std::cerr << "forgot input file and destination dir" << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    std::string input_file = argv[1];
    std::string output_directory = argv[2];

    std::cout << "Input file: " << input_file << '\n';
    std::cout << "Output dir: " << output_directory << '\n';
    size_t file_size = print_file_data(input_file);

    benchmark(IostreamTag{}, input_file, output_directory, file_size);
    benchmark(MmapTag{}, input_file, output_directory, file_size);
}
```